# Is it possible to add own function in transform.compose in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am using a pre-trained Alex model. I am running this model on some random image dataset. I want to convert RGB images to YCbCr images before training.

I am wondering is it possible to add a function on my own to `transform.compose`, For example:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
  ycbcr(), #something like this
  transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
  transforms.ToTensor(),
  transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])
```

where,

```
def ycbcr(img):
   img = cv2.imread(img)  
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2ycbcr)
   t = torch.from_numpy(img)
 return t

training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(link_train ,transform = transform_train)

training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=96, shuffle=True)
```

Is this process correct? Please help me on how to proceed?

Comment: What's `transforms` here? Also `bgr2gray` basically is: `gray = 0.2989*red + 0.5870*green + 0.1140*blue` so you can just use a matrix multiplication.

Comment: I am so sorry for the mistake, I want to change all my images to YCbCr before feeding it to the model, Therefore I used transform. compose, but it wasn't working.  I want to add my own function in transform.compose.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a custom transformation to `torchvision.transform` by defining a class.

To understand better I suggest that you read the [documentations](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

In your case it will be something like the following:

```
class ycbcr(object):
    def __call__(self, img):
        """
        :param img: (PIL): Image 

        :return: ycbr color space image (PIL)
        """
        img = cv2.imread(img)  
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2ycbcr)
        # t = torch.from_numpy(img)

        return Image.fromarray(t)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__+'()'
```

Notice that it gets a PIL image and return a PIL image. So you might want to adjust your code properly. But this is the general way to define a custom transformation.